# Query Weekdays and Holiday

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables:

`Holiday` and `EmpLog`

I need to select only the dates that are not present in `Emplog` (those days are WEEKDAYS and NOT equal to Holidays ONLY)

For example, I haven't logged this day: Dec 18, 2012.

So the output will be dec 18,2012

Comment: May you please post a code that illustrates how you are connecting to the SQL database? :)

Comment: It sounds like you want all dates throughout time that are weekdays, but not in your `Holiday` or `EmpLog` tables, correct?  Might restricting the results to a smaller range be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, I assume the following:

1. You have an EmpLog table, that has the datestamp of all the dates the Employee was present.
2. You have a Holiday table that has a list of dates that were either Weekends or Holidays
3. You need to find out all the dates that were working days, but a given employee was not logged

If these assumptions are correct, then this code will work:

```
--Declare variables to hold date values 
DECLARE @MyDate    DATETIME, 
        @FirstDate DATETIME, 
        @LastDate  DATETIME 

SELECT @MyDate = Getdate() -- OR Pass whatever date you want 

--Populate variable with values of first date and last date of the given month 
SELECT @FirstDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(dd, -( Day(@mydate) - 1 ), 
                                         @mydate), 
                           101), 
       @LastDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), Dateadd(dd, -( Day( 
                                        Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate)) ), 
                                                    Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate)), 
                   101) 

--Declare table variable to hold date values for the entire month 
DECLARE @AllDates TABLE 
  ( 
     datevalue DATETIME 
  ) 
DECLARE @Lastday INT 

SET @Lastday = Datepart(d, @LastDate) 

DECLARE @Days INT 

SET @Days = 1 

-- Populate table variable with all days of the month 
WHILE @Days <= @Lastday 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO @AllDates 
      SELECT @FirstDate 

      SET @FirstDate = Dateadd(d, 1, @FirstDate) 
      SET @Days = @Days + 1 
  END 

--Query joining the EmpLog table and Holiday Table, using Left Outer Join  
SELECT AD.datevalue 
FROM   @AllDates AD 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emplog EL 
                    ON AD.datevalue = EL.datevalue 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN holiday H 
                    ON AD.datevalue = H.datevalue 
-- Where clause to return only dates that do not appear in EmpLog or Holiday tables 
WHERE  EL.datevalue IS NULL 
       AND H.datevalue IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Rajan

Comment: Hi sir this is helpful, but the output is NULL. 26 rows NULL.

How can i display the dates?

Comment: Looks like you are selecting from your tables - EmpLog / Holidays and not from the table variable. Could you post your SQL here?

Comment: Sir Raj! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE CODE! VERY HELPFUL.IT WORKS!!!

Comment: Sir how about the Weekends? Still the output includes the Saturdays and Sundays. How can I exclude to my query?

Comment: Does you Holiday table only have Holidays and not weekends?

Comment: Yes sir only Holidays like Christmas but not include the Weekends.. How can i make it sir? Thank you!

Comment: Add this line of code to the end of the query, after the WHERE clause - AND DATENAME(dw,AD.DateValue) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')

Comment: Sir Raj thank you so much! you help alot! this will benefit the employees on our company!

Comment: Sir Raj, is this possible to make this query as stored procedure? I am confused on how can i call it on my c# window app program.

Comment: Sure. Just put the whole code into a Stored Proc. You can make the @MyDate as an input variable.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this

```
select column1 
from thistable 
left join otherTable on 
thisTable.column1 = otherTable.column1 
Where thisTable.column1 IS NULL
```

Comment: No it's not like that.

For example:

For December 2012,I need the dates that will only return the WEEKDAYS() which is not equal to Holiday.Date && dates that are not present in EMplog table